# Updating table with enum

Tags: scala, slick, sangria

Trying to insert the information into DB that looks like this:

```
(UUID, EnumType)
```

with following logic:

```
var t = TestTable.query.map(t=> (t.id, t.enumType)) ++= toAdd.map(idTest, enumTest)))
```

but compiler throws an error for `TestTable.query.map(t=> (t.id,  t.enumType))` it's interpriting it as type `Iteratable[Nothing]`, am I missing something?

---

Test table looks like this:

```
object TestTable {
  val query = TableQuery[TestTable]
}

class TestTable(tag: slick.lifted.Tag) extends Table[TestTable](tag, "test_table") {
  val id = column[UUID]("id")
  val enumType = column[EnumType]("enumType")

  override val * = (id, testType) <> (
    (TestTable.apply _).tupled,
    TestTable.unapply
  )
```

Comment: Could you please share `EnumType` definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have following data structure:

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
  val Blue = Value("Blue")
  val Red = Value("Red")
  val Green = Value("Green")
}

case class MyType(id: UUID, color: Color.Value)
```

Define slick schema as following:

```
class TestTable(tag: slick.lifted.Tag) extends Table[MyType](tag, "test_table") {
  val id = column[UUID]("id")
  val color = column[Color.Value]("color")

  override val * = (id, color) <> ((MyType.apply _).tupled, MyType.unapply)
}

object TestTable {
  lazy val query = TableQuery[TestTable]
}
```

To map enum to SQL data type slick requires implicit [MappedColumnType](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/userdefined.html#scalar-types):

```
implicit val colorTypeColumnMapper: JdbcType[Color.Value] = MappedColumnType.base[Color.Value, String](
  e => e.toString,
  s => Color.withName(s)
)
```

Now you can insert values into DB in this way:

```
val singleInsertAction = TestTable.query += MyType(UUID.randomUUID(), Color.Blue)

val batchInsertAction = TestTable.query ++= Seq(
  MyType(UUID.randomUUID(), Color.Blue),
  MyType(UUID.randomUUID(), Color.Red),
  MyType(UUID.randomUUID(), Color.Green)
)
```